# Custom character separator with ngModel is not working properly

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I want to format the entered number inside a textbox with a character separator in AngularJs.

I have created a directive to do the formatting. The directive is generating proper output but cannot update the `ngModel` properly.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="aadhaar" dashsep="'-'">

.directive('dashsep', function($timeout) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        dashsep: '=',
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
    },
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind("keyup", function (event) {
            var formattedAdh = "";
            //console.log(element.val());

            var test = element.val().toString();

            for(var i=0;i<=test.length-1;i++){
                //console.log(test[i]);
                if(i%4 === 0 && i>0){
                    formattedAdh+= scope.dashsep;
                }
                formattedAdh += test[i];
            }

            // Following script is not updateing the ngModel/textbox with the formatted value properly //
            /*
                //element.val(scope.$eval(formattedAdh));
                // OR
                //scope.ngModel = formattedAdh;
            */

            // Following output is showing proper value IF ABOVE SCRIPT IS COMMENTED //
            console.clear();
            console.log(formattedAdh);
        });
     }
   };
 });
```

Full script is provided into this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8eZeTe0P3rGVv06znUyJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the sample code, I think you are trying to add a dash after every 4 characters. That is, when the user types in "aaaabbbbcccc", you expect "aaaa-bbbb-cccc" to be displayed in `input[text]` and the scope model to update accordingly.

Given this assumption, you'll want to call `$setViewValue` with the formatted view value instead of updating the scope model expression directly. This is important because `$setViewValue` syncs your new view value with `ngModelController`'s internal view value and internal model value before updating the scope model expression.

Assuming the new scope model has changed successfully - that is, it passes parsers and validators, then`$viewChangeListeners` will run. From there, you can call `$render` to update the DOM with the new view value.

Here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ISK9r66SGnmZU4Uk6is7?p=preview) with changes.

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
    element.on('keyup', function (event) {
      var viewValue = element.val().toString();

      // add a dash every 4 characters
      if ((viewValue.length + 1) % 5 === 0) {
        viewValue += scope.dashsep;
      }

      // angular updates the internal view value, internal model, then scope model based on DOM
      ngModelController.$setViewValue(viewValue, event);
    });


    ngModelController.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
      console.log(ngModelController.$modelValue);
      // when model changes, call $render to display the latest view value
      ngModelController.$render();
    });
})
```

If you're looking to get a more in-depth explanation of ngModelController, this article may help: https://medium.com/product-at-catalant-technologies/i-have-to-relearn-angulars-form-api-every-time-i-use-it-83287c521968#.f5hle083e